# How to use wikitude samples?

Tags: sdk, installation, augmented-reality, sample, wikitude

I'm very new to android developing and AR, I installed Wikitude from this [link](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/imagerecognition.html#imageontarget)

But now I don't know how i must use samples in this [link](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/imagerecognition.html#imageontarget)

Please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the problem you're experiencing?

Comment: Yes, I finished this section "Setup your project" in first link, but i don't know where i must put sample codes and run them! In second link "Image Recognition" i just can see a sample code but it is not a sample app source to import in Eclips and run as a ready sample please help me to run first sample as a ready sample app. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the provided SDK sample application, which comes open sourced with the [Wikitude SDK](http://www.wikitude.com/download) - here you will find the JavaScript counterpart to the mentioned [Wikitude SDK Documentation](http://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/android/imagerecognition.html#imageontarget).
You can then use the sample application to adjust the samples code or enrich your application by reusing the concepts.

Kind regards,
Andreas

Comment: Thanks a lot i found them.